# Redirecting & Rewriting URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So i'm trying to get my head around using .htaccess - My folder structure is:

`website.com/www2/p/Home`

What i'm trying to do is:

1. Redirect a URL to a subfolder (*website.com > website.com/www2/p/Home/*)
2. Change the new URL to remove folder names (*website.com/www2/p/Home/ > website.com/Home/*)

What i have so far that (kinda) works is the following:

**.htaccess in website.com/**

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch ^/$ /www2/p/Home/
RewriteRule !^/?www2/p www2/p%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

**.htaccess in website.com/www2/p/**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+www2/p([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

This works but it breaks all my links & relative paths in my php & images + js & css doesn't get loaded.

I thought changing `RewriteBase` would help but what i'm trying isn't working.

Edit:
Inside p/ are different folders - eg. Home, About, Contact etc, each containing index.php

My folder structure is as such:
[image: folder structure]

Comment: For the images, js etc either add a `/` at the start of the link or `<base href="www.website.com/www2/p/">` to the head tag of the webpage.

Comment: what is inside `/p` several PHP files and one is called home.php or several folders with a index.html? can you provide more information it will be needed to tell your how to rewrite that. Or do you want to specifically redirect only the home folder?

Comment: I've added folder clarification.